# Find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 up to 1000

Tags: c++, math, logic

I'm doing the problems on Project Euler in C++, but I'm not getting the right answers to the first one.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b;
    int c;

    for (int a = 0; a <= 1000;)
    {
        a = a + 3;
        b = a + b;
    }
    cout << b << "\n";

    for (int a = 0; a <=1000;)
    {
        a = a + 5;
        c = a + c;
    }
    cout << c << "\n";

    b = b + c;
    cout << b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

167835
101505
269340

Where's the error in my logic?

Comment: can you post the exact question from project euler? is 1000 the upper bound?

Comment: Please avoid linking your code off an external site. If the link stops working, then this question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: Sorry about that Armen, I'll do that from now on.

Comment: bear in mind the answers here can make your current solution work but there are much more efficient solutions to this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding all values that are both multiples of 3 **and** 5 (i.e. multiples of 15) twice.  Additionally, you will also include 1002 and 1005, which probably isn't intended.

Comment: Thank you, I added an if statement to check if a was over 1000 before adding it to b and another loop to remove multiples of 15 and arrived at the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're double counting numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5 (i.e. multiples of 15).

Answer (score 2):

Consider, Find the sum of all multiples of 3 up to 20?

Ans : =>

3, 6, 9, 12, 15  this are multiples of  3 up to 20

Sum of all multiple of 3 up to 20 is => [3 + 6 +9 + 12 + 15]

(3 + 6 +9 + 12 + 15)   you can rewrite in following way

3 (1+ 2+3 +4+5 )  = > 3 (15) => 45

sum of sequence can be calculated using following formula

K(K+1)/2 = > here  K is 5  => 5 (5+1)/2 = >15

In general, We can say that multiple of any number (N) within given range R

K = R/N;

N* (K (K+1))/2

In our case R =20 and N =3

```
int sumDivisibeBy(int R, int N)
{
   int K = R / N;
   int  SEQSUM =  ((K*(K + 1)) / 2));
   return (N*SEQSUM)
}
```

In your case you need to call this function thrice =>

sumDivisibeBy(1000,3) + sumDivisibeBy(1000,5)-sumDivisibeBy(1000,15)

Comment: Can you add some description? It would be usefull for users to understand your code faster

Comment: is it fine?@-goto

Answer (score 0):

Along with double counting multiples of 15, your increments are in the wrong order. If you increment `a` first, you will have values above 1000. Also I'm not sure about c++ initializing ints, but maybe set them equal to 0, at least for readers.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't bother incrementing by 3 and by 5, you can increment by 1 and check whether numbers are divisible by 3 or by 5. Computers are designed for number crunching.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i%3 == 0 || 
        i%5 == 0)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
}
cout << "SUM:" << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Yeah that was the solution I saw most often online but I wanted to make my method work more then just copy another's. Out of curiosity though, I tried your method and got the wrong answer. Not sure why, I didn't take much of a look at it.

Comment: Probably should be strictly less than 1000, methinks.

Comment: Leon - the exact question is "Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

Comment: well if it below 1000, then it should be < 1000 not <= 1000

Comment: is the question clear whether to count numbers which are multiple of both 3 AND 5?

Answer (score 0):

While others have posted exactly where you've erred, you should be trying to figure out how you got the wrong answer as well.

In your case, you could have written all the values you determined to be multiples of 3 and multiples of 5; then you could have analyzed the 333 multiples of 3 you should've seen and the 199 multiples of 5 you should've seen.

I don't want to give away the keys to finding the actual solution (despite the fact that others have already) but part of the problem solving at PE is debugging.